# Performance wise is better to use global static variables or local variables?

Tags: java, android, static, global-variables, local-variables

I have an app that continuously check for matches into a text.
Snippet:

```
public boolean method()
    {
        if(Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("TEST1"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(text).find())
            return true;
        if(Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("TEST2"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(text).find())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Since this method gets called a lot, I thought what if I make static global variables instead of creating Pattern inside the method each time gets called.
Therefore:

```
     private static final Pattern TEST_1 = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("TEST1"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    private static final Pattern TEST_2 = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("TEST2"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

 public boolean method()
    {
        if(TEST_1.matcher(text).find())
            return true;
        if(TEST_2.matcher(text).find())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Would doing this increase the performance in the long run and, most importantly, prevent the app from being killed by the Android OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would doing this increase the performance in the long run

Yes. You are avoiding object instantiation and cutting down on garbage collection needs.

> prevent the app from being killed by the Android OS?

No.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Regarding the app being killed by the OS, could you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76441734/preprocessing-image-with-opencv-for-ocr-is-too-much-heavy-and-app-gets-killed-by

Comment: I can confirm my app is now faster. What about memory consumption though?

Comment: @zaxunobi: At any single point in time, the active memory consumption will be the same. However, by creating (and letting go of) fewer objects, you create less garbage that the garbage collector needs to clean up.

Comment: I understand, thank you! Could you please tell me if the memory consumption will be the same also in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76446012/tesseract-ocr-less-memory-consumption-by-avoiding-new-instances-of-tessbaseapi?

Comment: @zaxunobi: Whether what you are doing will work depends a lot on that third-party library, which I have not used.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Pattern` is [marked](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) as thread safe:

> Instances of this (Pattern) class are immutable and are safe for use
> by multiple concurrent threads. Instances of the Matcher class are not
> safe for such use.

It would work and will increase performance. It depends on you application, but in general it's unlikely that the impact would be significant enough to be noticeable. Probability that gain would turn out to be such crucial to prevent app from being killed even way lower, so I would say it would **not** prevent app from being killed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your code gets faster but you should pay attention to your method flow too.
for example some times you can avoid some if test like this in your code.
and even by making some methods static in util class then you will not need creating object for using that method.

```
private static final Pattern TEST_1 = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("TEST1"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
private static final Pattern TEST_2 = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("TEST2"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

public static boolean method(String text) {
    return TEST_1.matcher(text).find() || TEST_2.matcher(text).find();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is the common way to reduce object creation in Java.

The *final* keyword doesn't have the effect you're imagining.
That is used to prevent accidently writing over a variable.

It's commonly used in team environments, to signify that a variable needs to maintain it's value.

*[Variables (The Java™ Tutorials >

Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)*.

> *"... Additionally, the keyword final could be added to indicate that the [value] will never change."*

And, the *static* modifier is an interesting idea.
If you plan on creating multiple instances of the class, then it would help.

If it's just one instance, it wouldn't apply.

Also, you mention the following.

> *"Would doing this ... prevent the app from being killed by the Android OS?"*

This, I am unsure of.
You'll have to review the constraints of either the *[Dalvik VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software))* or the newer, *[ART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime)* runtime environment.

As a final note, you can combine your *[regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended) pattern*.

```java
private static String regex = Pattern.quote("TEST1") + "|" + Pattern.quote("TEST2");
private static Pattern TEST = Pattern.compile(regex);

public boolean method() {
    return TEST.matcher(text).find();
}
```